# is there any libary for instagram story progressbar?

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there any libary for a progress bar with a 10 second delay like Instagram story. In instagram story its goes 5-7 seconds with the progress bar.

iam very thankful for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [instagram-story-react-native-expo](https://github.com/codingki/instagram-story-react-native-expo)

I used this in all my projects in which I need story type feature